# It's possible to convert String[]="hello"; into Drawable images folder?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-drawable

My question is,i want to add images in Viewpager.I was trying to implemnet this and i'm successfully implement it.But now in ViewPager the text is shown with string[] value and i'll want to convert this string into Drawable images,is it's possible please help me out,
i'll provide the little bit code for understanding my question see below,

```
class TestFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements       IconPagerAdapter  {

private static String image1="R.drawable.splash";
private static String image2="R.drawable.splash";
private static String image3="R.drawable.splash";
private static String image4="R.drawable.splash";

protected static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { image1, image2, image3, image4 };
protected static final int[] ICONS = new int[] {
       // R.drawable.perm_group_calendar,
       // R.drawable.perm_group_camera,
       // R.drawable.perm_group_device_alarms,
        //R.drawable.perm_group_location
};

private int mCount = CONTENT.length;

public TestFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return TestFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mCount;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
  return TestFragmentAdapter.CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length];
}

@Override
public int getIconResId(int index) {
  return ICONS[index % ICONS.length];
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    if (count > 0 && count <= 10) {
        mCount = count;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of String image1="R.drawable.splash", you can use int image1=R.drawable.splash; and use CONTENT array type as int. It may work for you.

Comment: will you please hint me some line of code?

Comment: pass your int image reference id into TestFragment and directly use this in  your fragment for showing image

Answer (score 1):

```
    try {
        //packagename+sourceID,you should replace this String value to yours
        String sourceString = "com.yourpackagename.R.drawable.splash";
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String[] splits = sourceString.split("[.]");

        for (int i = 0; i < splits.length - 2; i++) {
            if (i != 0)
                stringBuffer.append(".");
            stringBuffer.append(splits[i]);
        }
        stringBuffer.append("$");
        stringBuffer.append(splits[splits.length - 2]);

        Class<?> cls = Class.forName(stringBuffer.toString());

        int idValue = cls.getField(splits[splits.length - 1]).getInt(splits[splits.length - 1]);

        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context, idValue);
        //this is what you want!
        Drawable imageDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(image);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```